# MPI Scatterv to a "sub"-communicator (using COMM_WORLD.Split() ) does not work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, mpi, mpi4py

I run the script below using  `mpirun -n 40 python script.py`. The aim is to parallelize the function func. What happens here is that the pool of 40 "workers" is split into 5 blocks of 8 "workers" (Each block with its own color ofcourse). 
I generate arguments (gen_args) for each block and flatten these to a 1D numpy array. Then I use ScatterV, to scatter this flattened array to the "workers" in **one** block. The scattered value is caught in the variable recv_args.

Everything works well (based on the print outputs I've seen), except for the `block_comm.Scatterv([send_data,counts,displacement, MPI.DOUBLE], recv_args, root=0)` Somehow it sets all the array elements of recv_args (in all ranks) to zero (Keep in mind, they are ones initially in all ranks) 
What am I missing here?

Here is the MCVE:

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI

def func(arg1, arg2,arg3):
  return arg1+arg2+arg3

def gen_args(const, n_iter):     #More complicated ofcourse in reality
  return const*np.arange(n_iter*3).reshape((n_iter,3))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    world_comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    world_size = world_comm.Get_size()    #  normally 40
    world_rank = world_comm.Get_rank()

    block_size = 8
    blocks = int(world_size/block_size)

    color = int(world_rank/block_size)
    key = int(world_rank%block_size)

    block_comm = world_comm.Split(color,key)
    #Effectively world_comm (size=40) is now split in 5 blocks of size=8

    block_rank = block_comm.Get_rank()
    print("WORLD RANK/SIZE: {}/{} \t BLOCK RANK/SIZE: {}/{}".format(world_rank, world_size, block_rank, block_size))

    recv_args= np.ones(3)
    counts = tuple(np.ones(block_size)*3)
    displacement = tuple(np.arange(block_size)*3)

    if block_rank==0:
      send_data = gen_args(color, block_size).flatten()
      print(send_data)
    else:
      send_data = None

    block_comm.Scatterv([send_data,counts,displacement, MPI.DOUBLE], recv_args, root=0)
    print(block_rank,recv_args)
```

Comment: `color=0` on the first 8 tasks, so `recv_args` should be zero here. What if you `block_size=2` and run with 4 tasks ? Can you upload the output ? Note this is not a [MCVE] strictly speaking since you do not validate the output (e.g. `recv_args`). Which MPI library is `mpi4py` built on top of ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet you're right, the answer from that link helped me.  I thought I was doing something wrong with the Splitting, But the problem  was with the automatic datatypes of my numpy arrays. I always have to force them to numpy.float64.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the datatypes of the send_data and recv_args (as can be seen here too: [How to scattering a numpy array in python using comm.Scatterv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329492/how-to-scattering-a-numpy-array-in-python-using-comm-scatterv) ). They have to be of datatype np.float64, when I declare the datatype as MPI.DOUBLE for Scatterv.

The following changes were made:

```
def gen_args(const, n_iter):  
  return const*np.arange(n_iter*3,dtype=np.float64).reshape((n_iter,3))
```

and

```
recv_args= np.ones(3,dtype=np.float64)
```